# Can i buy a license to create a Pokemon game?

Tags: game-design

Is there a way to purchase a license to create a Pokémon game? Would I be able to pay owners or the Pokémon name and creators of concept and whoever has permission to make games a fee to make my own game?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about obtaining the rights to a specific game.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes, practically it's very, very unlikely (or simply too expensive). You'd most likely have to pay the initial license owner, since other licensees might not be allowed to sub-license anything. We're typically not lawyers here and you should ask such questions a real lawyer if you're serious about something.

Personal opinion: Screw the idea. :) Create your own IP/game world/setting. That way you're in full control, people might call it a knock-off, yet you'd have far more freedom. If your game idea doesn't work without the Pokemon label on it, it's most likely not good enough anyway to interest anyone in playing it.